# form action downloads the php file instead of

Tags: php, html

I have this form on my website:

```
<div class="searchBar">
    <form action="searchDB.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" class="searchBarInput" bdo dir="rtl" name="k">
        <input type="image" class="searchBarIcon" src="../images/searchBarIcon2.png" border="0" alt="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

and when I press "enter" or press the icon. the searchDB.php file is being
downloaded instead of running the php file..

here's the code inside the php(its only for checking the mechanics of the connection between php and HTML..)

```
<?php
echo"This is a php file!";
?>
```

PS Ive tried downloading WAMP and installing it, nothing heppend.
and I follows a tutorial on youtube about how to install PHP on your computer, nothing changed there aswell.. anything I can do?

Comment: Simple, php isn't setup correctly.

Comment: Woh woh woh, start again mate. Download XAMPP, follow on screen instructions, will set everything up for you. Drop your site in the htdocs directory of the XAMPP folder and retry it.

Comment: You need to start apache in WAMP.

Comment: @Octopi what do you mean by "start apache in WAMP"?
AdamJeffers I'll try the XAMPP solution now..I'll let you know after ive finished downloading and installing.

Comment: Yes, do what adamJeffers suggested

Comment: @AdamJeffers I did everything as you've said I downloaded XAMPP and followed the installation as it showed, eventually I dropped my webpage into the htdocs directory. and still it tries to download the file instead of running it.. is there something I need to do in the XAMPP control panel to make it work?

Comment: No I don't think it's a PHP config issue... eerrrmmmm

Comment: Could it be a relative path issue? action="searchDB.php" or action="/searchDB.php" or action="../searchDB.php". It's difficult to say without seeing the complete picture.....

Comment: and what exactly are you expecting to happen as a result of submitting the form?

Comment: they are in the same directory so the relative path is correct.
I expect it to open a page and echo:"this is a php file"..

Answer (score 2):

Your PHP file is probably in the wrong folder or you are accessing it with a 'local file' URL that starts with file:// .(yes, that a different slash). Remember, PHP is a server-side language, it requires a "web server" to "serve" you pages, it's not like opening or running any file with any action like in Explorer. Typically, in WAMPP (or XAMPP), there is a htdocs folder in which you put all the web-serverable files. XAMPP already places some sample files. The URL will look like : "http:\locahost:nnn\index.php" where nnn is usually a port number, with index.php in the htdocs folder. Typically, you put your files in a subfolder inside htdocs, and include that in the URL.

Comment: Ive dropped all my websites's files into the www folder(which apperantly is the ht docs version of WAMP) still nothing happened.. is there something I should do differently in the action="" part?

Comment: WAMPP has a control panel or menu item kind of thing, where you start and stop the services, apache, mysql etc. Do check whether the required services have started. If you have a sample php file shipped with WAMP in the www folder, such as a small file that accesses phpinfo to give information about whether PHP is set up properly, open that file in your browser, by giving http:\\localhost....  type URL and see if it works.